# How to change the first character to a number?

Tags: java, string

Say if I have a string like `String reg = "a1"`, I need to change the first character of `a1` to the number 0 so then it becomes `01` and if the string is `c1`, it should be `31`. What is the best possible way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to compute. How does changing the first character of `"a1"` to 0 leave you with `00`?

Comment: something wrong in wht you say. do u mean c1 to 20 because a1 00 b1 10 c1 20

Comment: Changed it! What I meant was 01!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
char c = reg.charAt(0);
if(c >=97 && c <= 122) {
    c = c - 49;
}
String result = c + reg.charAt(1);
```

P.S
I'm assuming you meant that:

```
a1 → 01
c1 → 21
```

Meaning that a is 0, b is 1, c is 3, etc...